# Variable name is not defined

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

So basically I'm trying to loop through my sub-directories and files (images), such that each sub-directory contains two images, one that starts with the word `first`, and one that starts with the word `second`.

What I would like to do is that in each sub-directory I would like to assign the image that starts with `first` to the variable `img1`, and that which starts with `second` to `img2`.

Here's what I got:

path = '/my_path/'

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith('first'):
            img1 = numpy.asarray(Image.open(root + '/' + file))
        if file.startswith('second'):
            img2 = numpy.asarray(Image.open(root + '/' + file))

    print 'Image 1 is:'
    print img1
    print 'Image 2 is:'
    print img2
```

When I run the above code however, I get the following:

```
Image 1 is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print img1
NameError: name 'img1' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What if no filename starts with `first`?

Comment: I made sure that the only file names in each sub-directory either start with "first" or "second".

Comment: Is it the case that you will have a file starting with either "first" or "second", or can you have both types?

Comment: Maybe all the subdirectories have a `first` file, but what about the directory where you start your search?

Comment: @Reti43 Yes, I can have both types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your function with '`/my_path/`'. Then adding a '`/`' to the root which == '`/my_path/`' which gives you '`/my_path//filename`'.

A better method for joining the root path to the filename would be to use:

```
img1 = numpy.asarray(Image.open(os.path.join(root,file))
```

This will avoid any mixed up double slashes or forward versus backward slashes. Also, as others have pointed out, if you are definitely going to use a variable in your code then it should be defined outside of conditional statements, otherwise it may never get defined.

Comment: I think this was the main issue as you mentioned "if you are definitely going to use a variable in your code then it should be defined outside of conditional statements, otherwise it may never get defined". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Your code
if file.startswith('first'):
        img1 = numpy.asarray(Image.open(root + '/' + file))
```

You have your code so you only define `img1` if that condition is met. If it's not met (i.e. no file starts with 'first'), `img1` will not be defined. So then when you try to print img1, python has no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: While you explain the problem, suggesting a solution might also be helpful. For example, `img1 = np.asarray(...) if file.startswith('first') else None`.